# Laravel Livewire pass multiple parameters from view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I currently have a livewire component called live-data that I am passing a parameter orderNumber into as such:

```
@livewire('live-data',['orderNumber' => $order['order_number']])
```

Then in liveData.php I have:

```
public $orderNumber;
```

I would like to pass an additional parameter from the view to the livewire component named hasComponent.
I have tried the following:

```
@livewire('live-data',['orderNumber' => $order['order_number']],['hasComponent'=>$hasComponent])
```

and in liveData.php

```
public $hasComponent;
```

However this is not working as the variable is not being assigned the value from the view.
How is it possible to achieve this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: do like this : `@livewire('live-data',['orderNumber' => $order['order_number'],'hasComponent'=>$hasComponent])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this

```
@livewire('live-data',[
         'orderNumber'  => $order['order_number'],
         'hasComponent' =>  $hasComponent
         ])
```

For more : https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components